# Recursively finding if an element belongs to a list

Tags: python, algorithm, list, recursion

Say I have a list `x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4]`

Is there any recursive method to find if the element `a` (let's say `a = 3`) is in the list using only the condition `if not x:` and the instruction `list.pop([i])`?

Comment: Without any `for` or `while` ??

Comment: Yes, there is .. recursively. Hint: before the method is called recursively, pop off an item. Since `pop` removes the rightmost element, if you cannot use `len(lst)` (or `lst[-1]`) you'll also want to initially accept an `i`, and then supply an `i` decremented by one each recursive call, so `lst[i]` refers to the last element.

Comment: That seems like the sort of constraint that would be placed on homework... which you're supposed to do yourself.

Comment: I can pop it and compare it with `a` but at the end of the program I will have a print for each comparison and not a final print.

Comment: So where's your code, and what precisely is the problem with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def rec(lista, goal):
    if not lista:
        return False
    return (goal==lista.pop() or rec(lista, goal))
```

Comment: that's the answer I was looking for....thanks!

Answer (score 1):

define a function like:

```
def search(lst, key):
    if not lst:         # base case: list is empty
        return False
    elif lst[0] == key: # base case: current element is searched element
        return True
    else:               # recursive case: advance to next element in list
        return search(lst[1:], key)
```

then call `search(x, a)`

**Update:** If you want to implement this using pop just change the line lst[0] and lst[1:] with lst.pop()

Comment: While a better approach in operation selection, this doesn't use `pop` or `[i]` - which probably means `lst.pop()` and `lst[i]`, respectively. Homework problems are .. silly.

Comment: that is indeed a way but I am not allowed to make another comparison besides `if not lst:`

Comment: @TBone If you are sure the list is not empty then don't use that line (bad practice)

Comment: @user2864740 to use `pop` should try for example `lst.pop(0)` instead of `lst[0]`. As `pop(0)` is linear then better is to use `pop()`

Comment: @TBone If you want to implement this using `pop` just change the line `lst[0]` and `lst[1:]` with `lst.pop()`

Comment: The pop is not the point. The actual problem is the `elif lst[0] == key:`. I am not allowed to use another if instruction besides `if not lst:`. Someone else figured it out. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

something like:

```
def find(x,index):
   if index == len(array):
       return False;
   if array[index] != x:
        find(x,index + 1)
   else:
        return array.pop([index])
```

Comment: I imagine the OP's original requirement of using `list.pop([i])` was wrong. It is probably `lst.pop()` and `lst[i]`, which makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

use the following :

```
def find(test_list,element):
 try: 
  z=test_list.pop(0)    
  if element==z:
     return True
  return find(test_list,element)
 except IndexError:    
  return False
```